# Apache Hive installation Error

Tags: hadoop, hive

Does anymore knows which .jar file is inside org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.sessionstate ?
I have an error while installing Apache Hive into Hadoop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A quick `jar -tvf` shows that `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState` is in the `hive-exec-*.jar`.

Comment: thank you so much! Do you know what does this error means as well? jline.ArgumentCompletor.ArgumentDelimiter